# Is it possible to disable security on spring cloud stream starter apps?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am playing around with Spring Cloud Data Flow. I have successfully deployed SCDF on Kubernetes using the related [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_available_applications). When registering the [1.5.x based starter apps](http://repo.spring.io/libs-release-local/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/spring-cloud-stream-app-descriptor/Celsius.SR3/spring-cloud-stream-app-descriptor-Celsius.SR3.stream-apps-kafka-10-docker), everything is working as expected, no further configuration of the starter apps during the deployment of a stream definition is needed.

When using the [2.x based starter apps](http://repo.spring.io/libs-release/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/spring-cloud-stream-app-descriptor/Darwin.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream-app-descriptor-Darwin.RELEASE.stream-apps-kafka-10-docker), there are some changes introduced by the switch to Spring Boot 2.0 that need to be accommodated for, e.g. the actuator endpoints changed. For reference, here are the properties that I provide during the deployment of the stream:

```
app.*.management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health,info,binders
deployer.*.cpu=2
deployer.*.memory=4096
deployer.http.count=2
deployer.*.kubernetes.livenessProbePath=/actuator/health
deployer.*.kubernetes.readinessProbePath=/actuator/info
```

However, the readiness probe fails since the `health` and the `info` endpoint now seem to be protected by default. Therefore, the pods end up in crashloops since from the Kubernetes perspective they get never ready.

I worked around the situation by following the guide on [patching the starter apps](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/docs/Darwin.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_patching_pre_built_applications) that my stream definition relies on (e.g. `throughput` sink) like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({org.springframework.cloud.stream.app.throughput.sink.ThroughputSinkConfiguration.class})
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    protected static class ThroughputSinkSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to("health", "info")).permitAll();
        }

    }
}
```

Is there a way to specify this kind of security configuration via flags or properties? Shouldn't such a `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` be there by default to make the `health` and `info` endpoints accessible for Kubernetes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Artem's response is very relevant. I wanted to also share a few other approaches specific to security and OOTB apps.

1. In 1.6 SNAPSHOTs, we have recently added support via [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes#236](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-deployer-kubernetes/issues/236) to plug basic-auth realm to interact with secured actuator endpoints. They are applicable to both liveness and readiness probes. Here's the [commit/docs](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-kubernetes/commit/110abeb97d1130af96b6c099860a85cd1995a7bf) for your reference.
2. If you don't really want security at all, though not recommended, you can explicitly disable the Security configuration.

> dataflow:>stream create foo -- definition "http | throughput"
>
> dataflow:>stream deploy foo --properties app.*.spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration"

*(i.e., all the Apps in the `foo` stream definition will start with `SecurityAutoConfiguration` excluded)*

Comment: thanks Sabby. I see it the same way and yes Artems response is the way to go for production. At this stage I need a way to quickly disable the security configuration, so your answer is most relevant to me.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to look into the situation from the other angle and provide credential from the Kubernetes to get access to your secured Microservice.

The problem of the current status-quo that all the resources has to be protected.

You can generate your own static password and store it in the `application.properties` do not reconfigure Kubernetes for each application restart: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-security